# Kivy and OpenCv mask

Tags: python, image, opencv, kivy

I have made this simple code which show two images in kivy one image is the normal image and the other image is the mask

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock

import cv2
import numpy as np

class NormalImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NormalImage,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (600, 600)
        self.pos = (0, 0)

        self.img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
        cv2.imshow("normal image", self.img)

        buf1 = cv2.flip(self.img, 0)
        buf = buf1.tostring()
        image_texture = Texture.create(size=(self.img.shape[1], self.img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        self.texture = image_texture


class BinaryImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BinaryImage,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (600, 600)
        self.pos = (300, 0)

        img = NormalImage().img

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        hsvMin = np.array([19,150,100])
        hsvMax = np.array([30,255,255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,hsvMin, hsvMax)
        cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

        buf1 = cv2.flip(mask, 0)
        buf = buf1.tostring()
        image_texture = Texture.create(size=(mask.shape[1], mask.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        self.texture = image_texture


class RootWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(NormalImage())
        self.add_widget(BinaryImage())


class ImageApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def on_stop(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageApp().run()
```

[The normal image is shown properly, but the problem is that the mask isn't shown properly. It's supposed to show exactly the same as the image in the opencv window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD5ks.png)

[There is also some colored pixels on the mask, and it's supposed to be only black and white pixels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lf2E.png)
If you know how to show the mask properly in kivy let me know.

[If you want to try with image that I used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p53fd.jpg)

Comment: The result of `cv2.inRange` is a single channel image, yet in the call to `Texture.blit_buffer` you claim that `colorfmt='bgr'`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to convert the image.

Comment: Okay, it is working thank you